# Google Cloud Resource Manager - create projects inside folders

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create multiple projects inside my Organisation. My use case is:
1. I want to make an API call that creates a new project.
2. I want to create a new DialogFlow agent (chatbot).

Dialogflow API looks pretty straightforward. Since it's backend implementation, I am using service accounts to achieve this.

My problem is that when I'm trying to create a service account, it is always scoped to some project. I spent the whole day trying to give that service account all the access that I could find, but it's still giving me a `Forbidden` error.

Can someone explain to me if this is possible and if so - how should I configure it through the Cloud Console so that I can end up with a service account that creates projects (that can be scoped to some folder/project if it makes it easier)?

If the answer is yes - can I create multiple chatbots in one project? And what type of permissions do I need to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Add your service account member ID (email) at the organization or folder level. Then add Project Creator and Folder Creator roles: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-folders

Comment: Hey one question, are you creating the projects within an organization? Do you have access to that organization as an admin and can create folders, etc?

I ask this because I believe you only can assign the role `roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator` to the service account from the Organization's IAM&Admin page.

Comment: Hey Judith you are right, but I've managed to fix that issue by myself. They key thing here was John's answer. @JohnHanley if you read it as an answer, I am more than happy to flag it as such!